# Outlook SSO token error 13003 - The identity type of the user is not supported

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm getting an error when I try to obtain SSO token via method `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync` mentioned in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token).

I get different errors between the Outlook for the web and Outlook Desktop clients.

Outlook for the web:

```json
{
    "name": "User identity type is not supported.",
    "message": "The identity type of the user is not supported.",
    "code": 13003
}
```

Outlook Desktop (`16.0.8201.2207 32-bit`):

```json
{
    "name": "API Call Failed",
    "message": "Invalid input arguments.",
    "code": 5013
}
```

Something I have already tried:

1. Registered my add-in and provided admin consent for all users
2. Updating the add-in manifest to include `WebApplicationInfo` element.
3. Enabled `modern auth` suggested by [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32711.exchange-online-how-to-enable-your-tenant-for-modern-authentication.aspx):

My account is an admin, similar to `david@thirdpartyxx.onmicrosoft.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for reaching out.
You are on older build of Desktop Outlook (16.0.8201.2207 32-bit)
https://github.com/officedev/office-add-in-nodejs-sso recommends Office 2016, Version 1710, build **16.0.8605.1000** Click-to-Run, or later. Can you try that and let us know if you continue to experience the issue with build 8605 or later? In OWA it's not released yet - coming soon.

Comment: Yes, I made my account as a Monthly Channel insider and upgraded to 16.0.8625.2121, I finally obtained SSO token successfully. And in outlook web, the error remains the same, but it is expected as it is not released yet. Thanks for your help, appreciated!

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks for letting us know. OWA will come real soon, we're actively working on that.